# Can anyone explain where item comes from in this ajax .each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so im using the etsy api with javascript calling this ajax code

```
$.ajax({ url: etsyURL, dataType: 'jsonp', success: function(data) {
```

that returns an object array i guess?

and goes into this .each function

```
    if (data.ok) {          
        gallerySize=data.count;
        $.each(data.results, function(i,item) {  //assign array variables
           shopName=item.Shop.shop_name;
```

what im trying to figure out- is what exactly the each function is doing- i dont understand where the 'item' object comes from and am trying to access information outside of the .each function

for example- as it is right now- shop_name only needs to be declared once, it doesnt make sense to have this code every single time inside the each method. Surely there is a way to access whatever object array the ajax function calls?

Im sure this is a rather simple thing- i just dont understand the way the .each statement it setup and where the item it refrences is coming from

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `$.each()` iterates through `data.results`.

If it's an array, `i` is the index, and `item` is the value at that index.

```
data.results = [
    'foo',          // i = 0, item = 'foo'
    'bar',          // i = 1, item = 'bar'
    'baz'           // i = 2, item = 'baz'
]
```

If it's an object, `i` is the key, and `item` is the value under that key.

```
data.results = {
    'thefoo' : 'fooness',       // i = 'thefoo', item = 'fooness'
    'thebar' : 'barness',       // i = 'thebar', item = 'barness'
    'thebaz' : 'bazness'        // i = 'thebaz', item = 'bazness'
}
```

Comment: so basically the first instance of item = data.results[0]?

Comment: @Gazow no, it iterates through each item in `data.results`. meaning the code inside `$.each()` callback is executed per item in `data.results`

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look in [jQuery's code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js):

```
each: function( object, callback, args ) {
    var name, i = 0,
        length = object.length,
        isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( object );

    if ( args ) {
        if ( isObj ) {
            for ( name in object ) {
                if ( callback.apply( object[ name ], args ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( ; i < length; ) {
                if ( callback.apply( object[ i++ ], args ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
    } else {
        if ( isObj ) {
            for ( name in object ) {
                if ( callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( ; i < length; ) {
                if ( callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i++ ] ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return object;
},
```

See `for ( name in object ) {` and `for ( ; i < length; ) {`?
That is the looping of your argument.
*(very smart, jQuery, never seen anyone uses `for` like that)*

Now, see the `callback.apply( object[ name ], args )`?
That are your `i` and `item`.